# JQuery Mobile small checkbox

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to create a small checkbox / toggle like button using JQuery Mobile?

Placing them in a field set and set class=custom sort of does what I want, but I can't find a way to stretch the set so it fills 100% of the client width.

placing individual checkboxes in a grid with data-iconpos=center also sort of does it, but checkboxes don't quite support this mode.

Ideas?

Need 7 checkboxes horizontally. no text, just check or toggle.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

Make a sprite for the checkbox.

So when the image is "checked" showed checked sprite, and if it not, show the unchecked sprite.